# string localization in microsoft bot framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to build a bot that supports multiple languages with Bot Framework V4 using C#. I would like to use .resx to translate strings but I could not find any solution.  I tried to use the solution for Aspnet Core MVC 2 but it does not work.
So, can anyone give me an idea or any reference throught which I'll be able to implement string localization in Bot Framework V4?

Comment: One example I have seen is in location lookup library. I myself have created an extension of ResourceManager that is working well.

Comment: Can you give an example of this implementation?

Comment: to manage your resx files i suggest using Microsoft MAT: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matdev/2016/03/03/multilingual-app-toolkit-v4-0-update-1-is-available/

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core provides multi-language support by using Resource (`.resx`) files.

Based on [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/pull/429/files/42ecfc48efab3e3e87fa3bafec9b2108b8ce3e1b), You might want to do the following:

### Create the resources files

In your project, create a folder with the name "Resources", and then, add a **resource** file. This file will be your default language.

Make sure this file ends with `.resx`, and it use `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` as **Custom Tool**.

[image]

Now, add another resource file with the same name, but add `.{language ISO}` before the `.resx`:

[image]

(The file `BotStrings.Designer.cs` is auto generated by `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`)

For more information [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#resource-files).

### Control the language

To change the language of applications in .NET Core, you need to update the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` objects.

In the PR I mentioned, show how to do this by adding Middleware:

```cs
class SetLocaleMiddleware : Microsoft.Bot.Builder.IMiddleware
{
    private readonly string defaultLocale;

    public SetLocaleMiddleware(string defaultDefaultLocale)
    {
        defaultLocale = defaultDefaultLocale;
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var cultureInfo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Locale) ? new CultureInfo(defaultLocale) : new CultureInfo(turnContext.Activity.Locale);
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

        await next(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

In startup:

```cs
services.AddBot<MyBot>(options =>
{
    .
    .
    .
    options.Middleware.Add(new SetLocaleMiddleware("he-il"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check here, some help with Localizationconfig : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3799

Comment: Hi, the example refers to the framework version 3.x. I'm looking for a solution for the Bot Framework V4.